# UIToolBar + UINavigationController at the top of screen

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have read a few posts about people putting in either their own icons or Apple's icons into a toolbar, or as a customview into the rightBarButtonItem.  I was wondering if that's considered bad practice, ok practice, good practice, etc.  I was looking around, and I saw this: http://www.techtree.com/India/Features/Top_5_Productivity_Apps_for_iPad/551-115236-899-2.html.  In the Numbers app or Keynote App, it looks like they use a UINavigationController or some way to navigation + custom icons on the RHS.  I'd like to do the same, but I didn't know if this was considered bad practice, or something to be avoided in case Apple changes things down the line.  I basically want a couple bar button items and a UISearchBar.  Having a search bar at the bottom looks funny to me.  I noticed the Facebook app on the iPhone has a neat viewcontroller where you click the top left icon and it opens a way to navigate through their app.  I don't know if anyone has a tutorial of what's going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of apps that do what your talking about, so Apple shouldn't give you any problems.

" in case Apple changes things down the line."

On the other hand, they can be finicky about any kind of app, so there are no guarantees.  They may require all iPhone apps support landscape mode in the future.  You never know.

Look over the Apple User Interface Guidelines if you want to know more about their "recommended" control use.